# UITableViewController: scroll problem because of UITextField in my cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a grouped `UITableViewController` with one section and many rows. Each `cell` consists of two elements: a `UILabel` with a description and a `UITextField` for an input. A form, so to speak ;-)

Now I have a problem when I try to scroll the entire `UITableViewController`. Only on about half of my finger movements, it scrolls.

After I've studied the phenomenon more accurately, I noticed that the scroll works only if I hit the `UILabel` with my finger. If I hit the `UITextField` coincidentally, the `UITableViewController` does not scroll.

What can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could try is to create the `UITextFields` with `userInteractionEnabled = NO`, then when the cell is selected, set `userInteractionEnabled` and call `[textField becomeFirstResponder]` on it.

Although, I have just the same kind of tables and haven't noticed any scrolling problems...and I didn't set `userInteractionEnabled = NO`.   Have you perhaps set the cells' selection style to none?    In my tables, when I tap on the row, I get a row selection.    Swiping, even touching down over the text field, scrolls.    But in edit mode, where I disallow row selection, if I touch down over the text field and delay just a little before swiping, I don't get a scroll, and sometimes the text field becomes first responder.

Hopefully that will give some things to think about or experiments to try.

Comment: Great! Absolutely great! Set "userInteractionEnabled = NO" and call becomeFirstResponder inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath is an awesome idea. It works, thank you very much!